# Including full paths with overlayfs or unionfs

Tags: overlayfs

I have the following directories:

```
/some/path/dir1/subdir1/*
/some/path/dir1/subdir2/*
/some/path/dir1/subdir3/*
/some/path/dir2/subdir1/*
/some/path/dir2/subdir2/*
/some/path/dir2/subdir3/*
```

I want to create an overlayfs (or similar) mount that merges `subdir2` from both `dir1` and `dir2`.

```
mount overlay -t overlay -o lowerdir=/some/path/dir1/subdir2:/some/path/dir2/subdir2 /newpath
```

However, I want to keep their full paths, so that `/newpath` will contain the following:

```
/newpath/some/path/dir1/subdir2/*
/newpath/some/path/dir2/subdir2/*
```

I have not been able to find any information on this online... can this be done? Or is there another tool that could accomplish this for me?

Comment: But ... but ... but ... aren't you *already* in the desired situation? The two subdirectories are already "merged" in one tree and with their paths intact!

Comment: @AlexP Heh. True. Ideally, I would like subdir1 and subdir3 to be absent from the merged directory.